# How do I check version of wget to see if I have it installed already?

Tags: powershell, command-line, wget

I'm using windows 10 and have powershell installed. what is the command to check if I have it installed already and what directory do I need to be in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PowerShell, the `wget` command is actually an [alias](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_aliases) for the [`Invoke-WebRequest` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest) found in PowerShell version 3.0 and later. You can check which version of PowerShell you have by entering `$PSVersionTable` at a PS prompt:

```
PS> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      4.0
...
```

We can check to see if this cmdlet is available by using the `Get-Command` cmdlet:

```
PS> Get-Command wget 

CommandType     Name                          ModuleName
-----------     ----                          ----------
Alias           wget -> Invoke-WebRequest
```

The *actual* `wget` program itself (that PowerShell named the alias after) is typically found on Unix/Linux systems, not on Windows. Unless you installed a Windows port yourself, or you run a Unix-like environment like Cygwin or MSYS, you won't find this program installed.